# Jquery alert data attribute of element with style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a short question:

I have multiple elements with the same class, and i want to alert dynamically the data-index value of the the element with the style "display: block".

Here is my code:

```js
var test = $('.test').data('index');

alert( test );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test" style="display:none" data-index="0" href="#">foo!</a>

<a class="test" style="display:block" data-index="1" href="#">foo!</a>

<a class="test" style="display:none" data-index="2" href="#">foo!</a>
```

Comment: Try `$('.test[style*=block]').data('index')` ..

Comment: This one worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`:visible` can be used just like in CSS for this purpose

```js
var test = $('.test:visible').data('index');

alert( test );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test" style="display:none" data-index="0" href="#">foo!</a>

<a class="test" style="display:block" data-index="1" href="#">foo!</a>

<a class="test" style="display:none" data-index="2" href="#">foo!</a>
```